# FirebaseInstanceId: background sync failed: PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR, retry in 10s/20s/40s

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase token not generated in Asus mobile and few other devices although its working fine in most of the devices. How to resolve this phone Registration error?

Comment: Are the devices where the token is not being generated running Google Play Services?

Comment: @Authur Thompson Yes, device has play service 10+ running. Everything is up-to-date.

Comment: If the devices are running an up to date version of Play Services then the token should be generated, could you provide more details about the issue with the device at firebase.google.com/support?

Comment: I also have Asus device and, I also had that problem.
Try to restart your device, hope it will help.

Comment: Also facing this issue, got this error on htc one e8. Were you able to resolve the issue.